# Questions Regarding Data Availability and Consistency in YouTube Live Video Statistics using 'Reports: Query'

Tags: youtube-api

I am currently utilizing the [Reports: Query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query) method to extract daily statistics from YouTube Live videos. I have the following questions:

- Assuming videos receive sufficient traffic, how much time does YouTube take to publish statistics such as `estimatedMinutesWatched`?
- After publication, is it possible for these statistics to change? If so, what would be a safe lag time before querying video metrics?

Comment: Look for something in the docs about data latency